# design a user command and multiple inputs

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I am a JAVA beginner, and I've done some research. It turned out there is no such a way to deal with this problem. I'm assigned to design a prompt command with multiple data inputs, with only one scanner object.

Now, I've already achieved the following:

1. Set an array for saving the NimPlayer object.
2. Set the NimPlayer class for creating a unique NimPlayer object.
3. Set the counter, used as an index.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.print('$');
   String input = in.next();

   // initialize an array
   NimPlayer [] playerList = new NimPlayer[10];

   // create a position in the array
   int addUserCount = 0;
   if (input.equals("addplayer")) {
       String userName = in.next();
       String familyName = in.next();
       String givenName = in.next();

       addUserCount +=1;
       playerList[addUserCount] = new NimPlayer(userName, familyName, givenName); 

   }

   public class NimPlayer {
   String userName;
   String familyName;
   String givenName;

   public NimPlayer(String userName,String surName, String givenName) {
       this.userName = userName;
       this.familyName = surName;
       this.givenName = givenName;
   }
   public void setUserName(String userName) {
       this.userName = userName;
   }
   public void setFamilyName(String familyName) {
       this.familyName = familyName;
   }
   public void setGivenName(String givenName) {
       this.givenName = givenName;
   }    
   public String getUserName() {
       return userName;
   }
   public String getfamilyName() {
       return familyName;
   }
   public String getGivenName() {
       return givenName;
   }
   }
   ```

   the goal is to design like this:

   addplayer userName,familyName,givenName

So, that's why I use next() to identify the first word, and space is the default delimiter.

I am not sure how to do next. What should I do to add a feature that separates the inputs using ",".

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the [javadoc for `Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).  The [`useDelimiter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter-java.lang.String-) method might be what you're looking for.  Or it might be easier to read the rest of the line with `nextLine()` and then break the data apart using `String` method [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read lines with Scanner.nextLine(). Here is an example how you can type "username, surname, givenname" in one line and get splitted by String.split(",").

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); 

    String line = s.nextLine();
    String[] splittedLine = line.split(",");

    for(int i = 0; i < splittedLine.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("splitted line: %d. %s \n", i, splittedLine[i].trim());
    }
}
```

Input:

```
name, surename, username
```

Output:

```
splitted line: 1. name 
splitted line: 2. surename 
splitted line: 3. username
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out and your kind patience. I missed the split function. Now I successfully save the name in the array.